# Finding $\mathbb{E}(XY|XY>\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y))$

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value

> Assuming case where both $X$ and $Y$ are independent and normally distributed with different mean and variance how do I calculate $\mathbb{E}(XY|XY>\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y))$.

Assuming $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$,

I can't seem to integrate xy on the new $f(xy)$ as the $x$ and $y$ are separated most of the time.

And I am uncertain of the lower limit of integrating $f(x)f(y)xy$ as I am unsure of what lower limits for both $x$ and $y$ would guarantee $XY>\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$.

Answer (score 0):

As you say the x and y are separated most of the time, but you can get a very good approximation. We want to find $E\left(XY|XY>E(X)E(Y)\right)$. Because E(X)E(Y) is just a constant, let's call it C. Let's assume C>0, then the bounds are $x>0,y>\frac 3 x$ and $x<0, y<\frac 3 x$. So there are two regions to integrate and they are indeed separate, making things more difficult.

We first find $E(XY|XY>C,X<0)$. This is $$H_1=\int_{-\infty}^0\int_{-\infty}^{\frac 3 x} xy\frac{f(x,y)}{A}dydx$$ with $A=\int_{-\infty}^0\int_{-\infty}^{\frac 3 w}  f(z,w)dzdw$. That is, we reweighted the density - the denominator is just a constant and is the probability that x<0 and y>3/x.

The $E(XY|XY>C,X>0)$ can be calculated the same way as follows

$$H_2=\int_{0}^\infty\int_{\frac 3 x}^{\infty} xy\frac{f(x,y)}{B}dydx$$

with $B=\int_{0}^\infty\int_{\frac 3 x}^{\infty}  f(z,w)dzdw$ being another reweighting of the density.

Once you get these two expected values, the expected value of the overall $E(XY|XY>E(X)E(Y))$ must be between these two. But we can do better than just find bounds. Take the weighted average:

$$E(XY|XY>E(X)E(Y))\approx \frac{H_1A+H_2B}{A+B}$$

I am actually not sure if it is approximate or in fact equal.